# Table with CRUD actions

Tags: views, database

I'm using `Drupal 7`.
I've a custom table that I what do display and enable to Add, Edit and Delete items.
I tried [editableviews](https://drupal.org/project/editableviews) module but it doesn't work for me:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: result_indexes in editableviews_plugin_style_row_edit_table->insert_form_elements() (line 218 of C:\wamp\www\mypoc\sites\all\modules\editableviews\editableviews_plugin_style_row_edit_table.inc).
Notice: Undefined variable: result_indexes_reverse in editableviews_plugin_style_row_edit_table->insert_form_elements() (line 219 of C:\wamp\www\mypoc\sites\all\modules\editableviews\editableviews_plugin_style_row_edit_table.inc).
Notice: Undefined variable: result_indexes in editableviews_plugin_style_row_edit_table->insert_form_elements() (line 218 of C:\wamp\www\mypoc\sites\all\modules\editableviews\editableviews_plugin_style_row_edit_table.inc).
Notice: Undefined variable: result_indexes_reverse in editableviews_plugin_style_row_edit_table->insert_form_elements() (line 219 of C:\wamp\www\mypoc\sites\all\modules\editableviews\editableviews_plugin_style_row_edit_table.inc).
```

How to fix that error or is there anything else to use?

Comment: I would look into the data module (https://drupal.org/project/data). I can't remember off the top of my head all the details about it and CRUD but I would start there and build on that if it (ar some related module) doesn't already do what you need.